# How to use clang's LeakSanitizer on MacOS?

Tags: macos, address-sanitizer, leak-sanitizer

I'm macOS Big Sur. AFAIK, Valgrind doesn't support this OS yet. At least I've tried [this](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LeakSanitizer.html).

After some Googling, I switched to [LeakSanitizier](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LeakSanitizer.html) and tested this C code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
void *p;
int main() {
  p = malloc(7);
  p = 0; // The memory is leaked here.
  return 0;
}
```

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53456304/mac-os-leaks-sanitizer) pointed that clang shipped with macOS doesn't have `-fsanitize=address` support enabled. So I installed clang from homebrew:

```
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang --version
clang version 11.0.0
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin
```

OK, let's try it:

```
Ancalagon:Codes anta40$ /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -g -fsanitize=address leak1.c -o leak1
Ancalagon:Codes anta40$ ./leak1
Ancalagon:Codes anta40$
```

Nothing happens. Perhaps try `llvm-symbolizer`

```
Ancalagon:Codes anta40$ /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/llvm-symbolizer ./leak1
./leak1
```

Same result. Perhaps I'm missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable LeakSanitizer set `ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=1` or use `-fsanitize=leak` flag.

Also, according to [this](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/52461), if using the `clang` version 11.0 and `Xcode` version 11.3, use `clang` with `-mlinker-version=450` flag to avoid a linker error.

Example:

```
$ /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -g -fsanitize=address leak1.c -o leak1
$ ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=1 ./leak1
```

or

```
$ /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -g -fsanitize=leak leak1.c -o leak1
$ ./leak1
```

Comment: Seems that I have to use both `-fsanitize=address` and `ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=1`